# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script and priority

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js' );
function include_js(){   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js");
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jQueryui', "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js");
    wp_enqueue_script( 'stellar', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.stellar.min.js");
    wp_register_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/script.js",  array( 'owl-carousel', 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );                
}
```

In file script.js I loaded a function from 'owl-carousel' and I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
enter code here
```

This is strange because I added array('owl-carousel', 'jquery')in the last line on the code (which is above) so script.js should load after owl-carousel but it does not. I checked html code by pressing F12 and script.js had loaded before owl-carousel. Why? Where is my mistake?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is included with WordPress by default [in no-conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). In `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you need to use something like the following to make it available to you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Owl Carousel isn't working because it's using `$` as a shortcut, and `$` hasn't been assigned as a shortcut for jQuery.

Another option is to "dequeue" the included jQuery, and "enqueue" your own version.

Comment: You mean sth like this?
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();
 
});
The same error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the issue was that $ is not available as a shortcut for jQuery, you would get an error stating that it doesn't know what $ is.

The error here means that owlCarousel wasn't loaded or not initialized.

You should check in the console whether it displays an error while loading or running the owlCarousel script (also check in the network tab which URL was called and whether it's the right path).